# Ruby on Rails - How to keep the server running on remote server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having some issues here while trying to deploy my rails app, since whenever I start my server using "rails server" everything runs fine, but when I close the terminal, the server is shutdown.

How can I make it running continously?

Thank you

Comment: where are you trying to deploy? heroku or aws or digitalocean?

Comment: use rails s -d which will run as daemon.

Comment: Trying to deploy to digital ocean